# Should non-clickable elements that have tabindex="0" have :focus blue outline removed?

Tags: css, focus, accessibility, tabindex, outline

We have a project where the user needs to navigate trough the UI using the tab key.

To ensure sequential navigation we added tabindex="0" to these divs, which now can be navigated sequentially using tab key. that´s good.

But, we my question is if these divs, which are not clickable, should have the outline or not?

I know how to remove it , the question is if this the appropiate thing to do from an accesibility perspective?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're not clickable (or in a11y jargon 'operable'), they shouldn't really have `tabindex=0`. (There are some rare exceptions to this).

If by 'navigate' you mean 'browse with a screenreader' you're probably doing it wrong. Just use semantic HTML and let the screenreader take care of the navigation.

The question of whether the focus indicator is visible is secondary to that, but if it's not operable, it probably shouldn't have a focus indicator.

Comment: For some reason without the tabindex="0" the elements were ignored when navigating with tab using a screen reader. this lead to a lot of text being not read. what approach do you recommend to have these divs on focus when tab is pressed, and allow a sequential navigation that makes sense.  thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Made a new question around the use of tabindex and alternatives to overcome the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429116/what-alternative-to-tabindex-0-exists-that-makes-page-content-browsable-in-seq